# CreateUserWizard's LoginCreatedUser=false and email sending doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, createuserwizard

In CreateUserWizard I have set:

```
DisableCreatedUser="True" 
LoginCreatedUser="False"
```

but the user is logged on after it is created.

and also for sending a verification email I have added:

```
   <MailDefinition BodyFileName="~/EmailTemplates/NewAccountTemplate.htm" From="info@test.com" IsBodyHtml="True" Subject="Registration">
   </MailDefinition>
```

but no email is sent and even OnSendingMail is not fired.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was this default code in Register.aspx.cs

```
formsauthentication.setauthcookie(registeruser.username, false /* createpersistentcookie */);
string continueurl = registeruser.continuedestinationpageurl;
if (string.isnullorempty(continueurl))
{
   continueurl = "~/";
}
response.redirect(continueurl);
```